# Macbook Air crashed and now won't boot, stuck at Apple logo with loading bar. Disk utility can't unmount the drive to repair

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, mojave, startup

I have a Macbook Air that had what I think was a kernel panic the other day. What I have been told is that while the user was working, it crashed to a black screen with some info on it and then the computer rebooted.

Since this happened, it won't boot; it just sits on the Apple logo with the progress bar stuck around 50%.

I have booted to recovery to repair the disk and first aid fails because it can't unmount the disk. I tried to force unmount it from terminal and again first aid won't work because it can't find the disk.

I installed MacOS on an external drive and booted to that. I can see the drive and data, and am currently trying to migrate the data as part of MacOS setup on the external drive. I selected the option to transfer data from another startup disk and it found all users, Applications, and other settings. The only problem is that it's been running for about 24 hours and says it will take 96 hours to complete.

My question is whether that long of a timeframe is normal, or is there another way I can try to get the data off and reinstall MacOS on the internal drive to see if it fixes the issue.

Should I run CCC and try to copy the drive to another external drive, or would that create another un-bootable startup disk?

Alternatively, if I try to reinstall MacOS on the internal drive, that will leave the data intact and only reinstall the OS, right?

Of course it looks like Time Machine hasn't completed a backup to the network drive in some time, so I need to get a copy of the data before I try to do anything.

Comment: Boot in Verbose Mode (`Cmd`-`V`) and see where it hangs.  Take a pic and post it here.  How are you transferring the data?  WiFi?  USB 2.0?  How much data are you transferring? Without these details, we can’t tell you how long a transfer will take.  What model MBA specifically?